# Find the limit of transition probabilities: $p_{jk}^{(n)} \to e^{-\lambda/q} \frac{(\lambda/q)^k}{k!}.$

Tags: probability-theory

> A chain with states $E_0, E_1, ...$ has transition probabilities 
>   $$p_{jk} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{v=0}^j {j \choose v}p^vq^{j-v}\frac{\lambda^{k-v}}{(k-v)!}$$
>   where the terms in the sum should be replaced by zero if $v >k $. Show that 
>   $$p_{jk}^{(n)} \to e^{-\lambda/q} \frac{(\lambda/q)^k}{k!}.$$

To find the limit, I should derive $p_{jk}^{(n)}$ first. I was thinking that using the Chapman Kolmogorov identity $p_{jk}^{(n)} = \sum_z p_{jz}p_{zk}^{(n-1)}$, I might successively find  $p_{jk}^{(1)}, p_{jk}^{(2)}, ... $ and find the pattern somehow. However, the equation get too messy, and I am not sure if this is the right approach. I would appreciate if you give some hint.

Comment: The limit is for $n\to +\infty$ right?

Comment: There's a countably infinite number of states and $q = 1-p$?

Comment: @MiKiDe yes, you are right.

Comment: @Renard It wasn't mentioned in the question, but I think yes.